# Gravity and Centripetal Force

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gravity

I am making an application in Unity 3d where I want to code gravity and centripetal force myself but I am getting weird results, am I doing it right? This is my code:

```
public void Attract(MassObject[] _allMass)
{
    Vector3 F = new Vector3();
    Vector3 C = new Vector3();
    foreach(MassObject i in _allMass)
    {
        // gravity pull
        F.x = GV.gravity * ((mass * i.mass) / (obj.position.x - i.obj.position.x));
        F.y = GV.gravity * ((mass * i.mass) / (obj.position.y - i.obj.position.y));
        F.z = GV.gravity * ((mass * i.mass) / (obj.position.z - i.obj.position.z));

        // centripital force
        C.x = (mass * Mathf.Pow(vel.x,2)) / (obj.position.x - i.obj.position.x);
        C.y = (mass * Mathf.Pow(vel.y,2)) / (obj.position.y - i.obj.position.y);
        C.z = (mass * Mathf.Pow(vel.z,2)) / (obj.position.z - i.obj.position.z);
    }
    vel = F + C;
    Debug.Log(F);
    Debug.Log(C);
}
```

Comment: Define "weird results".

Comment: I am getting (-0.6, NaN, Infinity). i dont understand how I can get NaN or Infinity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few problems with this:

1. You are rewriting `F` and `C` with each `foreach` iteration, so you end up with the for for the last object in the list. You should add all the forces together using `+=` instead of `=`.
2. You should be using vector operations rather than manually calculating `x` `y` and `z`. Doing so would make the third error more obvious:
3. The formula is wrong. For example, this line:

   ```
   F.x = GV.gravity * ((mass * i.mass) / (obj.position.x - i.obj.position.x));
   ```

   with just a few things substituted is

   ```
   F.x = gravity coeff * (masses multiplied) / (distance **on the x axis** between objects.)
   ```

   What you really need is distance between objects, not just on the x axis. You can get this with a vector operation:

   ```
   float distanceSquared = (obj.position - i.obj.position).sqrMagnitude;
   ```

   Then you can use the [law of universal gravitation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_law_of_universal_gravitation#Modern_form) to get the magnitude of the force of gravity:

   ```
   float forceMagnitude = GV.gravity * (mass * i.mass) / distanceSquared;
   ```

   Finally, you need a direction. You can get that with vector subtraction and normalization, then multiplying by the desired magnitude:

   ```
   Vector3 force = (i.obj.position - obj.position).normalized * forceMagnitude;
   ```

   And now `force` is a vector pointing from `obj` to `i.obj` with the magnitude of gravity between the two objects. Add that to `F` to accumulate the force from each object and things should be good.
4. Your understanding of physics might be off. If `vel` is velocity, it is wrong to set it to the sum of two forces. I think you're better off learning about this from somewhere else, though. Understanding Newton's laws is a good start.